When the spectrum of a operator will be finite.
Let $X$ be a Banach space and $T \in K(X)$, which means that $T$ is a compact operator from $X$ to $X$. If $X$ is finite dimensional, do we have that spectrum $\sigma(T)$ is finite? (I mean there are a finite number of elements in $\sigma(T)$).
Otherwise, is there any other conclusion that we can conclude spectrum is finite.
And can anyone recommend a readable book for a beginner of spectrum decomposition, (which means that it haves enough content, and is easy to read.)

If $X$ is finite dimensional then the spectrum elements are just the eigenvalues. It's a very standard result that an operator over a finite dimension space has finitely many of them. (for example, they are the roots of the characteristic polynomial of $T$)

Not sure what you mean by metric here. A linear operator and linear transformation are the same thing. Here you assume $T$ is linear.

@Mark. Very sorry about that. I mean that when $X$ is finite-dimensional, then it is equivalent to $\mathbb{R}^n$. Hence, in this case, $T$ is linear transformation which we learn in algebre course. And $T$ can be regarded as a matrix $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Yes, if you choose a basis of a finitely dimensional space then any linear map can be represented by a matrix.
